# "Refreshing" the inspector in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This code runs every time a user starts up their server. It's meant to smooth out the process.

```
# Checking if the database has tables
inspector = inspect(engine)
tables = inspector.get_table_names()
print(tables)  # Should be "[]"

if not (tables):
    # There are no tables in the database.
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()
    print("Created database tables.")

del inspector
```

Next, we want to check every table and see if it's empty. If it is, then we print the name of the table.

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    # Iterating through all the tables in the database...
    inspector = inspect(engine)
    tables = inspector.get_table_names()
    print(tables) # Should return something like ['users', 'posts'] 

    for table_name in tables:
        # Does this table have any rows?
        result = connection.execute(
            "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {}".format(table_name))
        for row in result:
            if row[0] == 0:
                # This table doesn't have any rows.
                # So we fill it...
    del inspector
```

This code executes chronologically as shown.

Is there a better way of executing this procedure that **doesn't** require me to delete the inspector object and recreate it? I have a feeling this is not best practice.